# Ideal generated by a set of singular elements in a Banach algebra.

Tags: banach-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative unital Banach Algebra. Suppose for every $a\in A$, $\|a\|=1$, I get a singular element $b_a$. I know that each such $b_a$ is contained in a proper maximal ideal of $A$. Is it possible that all the $b_a$'s together are in aproper maximal ideal?

Comment: How is $b_a$ related to $a$?  Nothing you've told us prevents all $b_a$ from being in the same maximal ideal.  In fact nothing you've told us prevents all $b_a = 0$.

Comment: Basically, for every $a\in A$ I get an element $c_a$ and a scalar $\lambda_a$ such that  $\lambda_a\in \sigma(a+c_a)$. So I am treating $b_a= a+c-\lambda_a$

Comment: So for example you could have $c_a = -a$ and $\lambda_a = 0$?

Comment: I calculated and checked this case is possible for me only when $\|a\|=\frac{1}{\|(\lambda_a-a)^{-1}\|}$in my Banach algebra. So I should take that all $b_a$'s are not zero. And we have that $\lambda_a-a$ are invertible

Comment: Rather than adding conditions one at a time, why not tell us the whole problem?